# Sorting a string by moving k adjacent numbers to the end

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an algorithmic problem to solve, it looks like this:

We have sequence of length n with elements ranging from 0 to (k-1).

Example for n = 10, k = 3:
**2 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 2**

I have to sort this string, so it would look like this: 
**0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 2** (sorted subsets from 0 to k-1, surplus elements may not be sorted).

But it have to be sorted by moving k adjacent elements to the end and joining the rest, example:

**0 1 2 [2 0 2] 0 1**

**0 1 2 0 1 [2 0 2]**

In solution, **I can have assumption**, that there will be a certain number of redundant elements.

I have already invented naive algorithm to solve this:
http://pastebin.com/Q5CR99E7

...but I have to come up with 3 algorithms and I think that there may be more sophisticated solution.
I would be grateful for your ideas.

Comment: What is the solution (Step by step?) for your first example (2100210012)? The constraint is not clear

Comment: It is hard to tell, i will show on simpler example: 1 . 0[11]0 -> 00[11]   2.0[01]1 -> 01[01] (sorted)

Comment: Your "simpler example" doesn't make sense either: 0110: 01[1]0 -> 010[1] (single step). What is the source of this problem? looks like some info is missing

Comment: But you can move only k adjacent elements.